# Conceptual question about angles in geodesic

Tags: python, geodesic

I have an area enclosed by the top-left and bottom-right geographical coordinates. I am trying to sample boxes, each 100x100 meters within that area. The boxes must be square and I am trying not to use UTM coordinates, only GPS.

Here is the minimal reproducible example:

```
from geographiclib.geodesic import Geodesic
import math
import numpy as np

#patch coordinates
geod = Geodesic.WGS84
top_left = (51.018368486644285, 4.346176037842144)
bottom_right = (50.94998939731849, 4.417298379088093)

top_right = (top_left[0], bottom_right[1])
bottom_left = (bottom_right[0], top_left[1])

#area properties
inv_lon = geod.Inverse(top_left[0],top_left[1],top_right[0],top_right[1])
inv_lat = geod.Inverse(top_left[0],top_left[1],bottom_left[0],bottom_left[1])

area_width = inv_lon['s12']
area_height = inv_lat['s12']

#Both azi1 and azi2 return a very similar output, difference is average angle at the end is ~1e-7
azi_v = inv_lat['azi2'] #180 
azi_h = inv_lon['azi2'] #approx 90

num_lat = math.ceil(area_height/100)
num_lon = math.ceil(area_width/100)

lons = []
for i in range(num_lon):
    dir = geod.Direct(top_left[0], top_left[1], azi_h, 100*i)
    lons.append(dir['lon2'])
lats = []
for i in range(num_lat):
    dir = geod.Direct(top_left[0], top_left[1], azi_v, 100*i)
    lats.append(dir['lat2'])

angles = []
angles_azi1 = []
angles_azi2 = []
latv, lonv = np.meshgrid(lats, lons)
bboxes = []
for i in range(num_lon):
    for j in range(num_lat):
        if i!=0 and j!=0:
            bboxes.append(np.array([[lonv[i-1,j], latv[i,j]], [lonv[i, j], latv[i, j-1]]]))
            azi1 = geod.Inverse(bboxes[0][0,1],bboxes[0][0,0], bboxes[0][1,1], bboxes[0][1,0])['azi1']
            azi2 = geod.Inverse(bboxes[0][0,1],bboxes[0][0,0], bboxes[0][1,1], bboxes[0][1,0])['azi2']
            angles_azi1.append(azi1)
            angles_azi2.append(azi2)
            angles.append(np.mean([azi1, azi2]))

print(np.where(np.array(angles)<=45))
print(np.mean(angles))
print(np.mean(angles_azi1))
print(np.mean(angles_azi2))
```

In the `angles` list I store the average of azi1 and azi2 between the top-left and bottom-right corner of each box. When I just check azi1, the average per per box is 44.99971944606249 degrees, when I do the same with azi2, the average is 45.00082724586242. So far it makes sense, but what I don't understand is why the average of 'angles` is consistently above 45 degrees.

The following are the outputs of the code:

```
(array([], dtype=int64),)
45.00027334596245
44.99971944606249
45.00082724586242
```

Am I mistaken in thinking that the average of azi1 and azi2 between the top-left and bottom-right corner of a truly square box should be exactly 45 degrees?

Comment: Your rectangles aren't rectangles -- They are spheroidal trapezoids (smaller parallel toward closest pole)

Comment: @Vince You are right, I did not notice it. Thanks!